# How can you find out who hacked your accounts and sent out dirty messages on your email and snap chat

Tags: network

My College email account was hacked and several dirty messages went out to my teachers and boss. My Snap Chat was also hacked and messages were sent out to my parents only. How can I find out who did this.

Comment: Were the dirty messages forwarded to you in original form (= with full headers, unmodified)?

Comment: Is any of your E-mail addresses found on this server: https://haveibeenpwned.com/ ?

Comment: Ask to your college from which IP and time, were sent the suspicious messages.

Comment: No, they were written from my account and sent to people on my contact list

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, for your college email account you can consult and report it to your school administration. They will investigate your login activity and they can check the email header to figure out the source of those malicious emails. So basically they will do a forensic scan of your account.

Secondly, for your Snapchat Account, you should enable security features of login activity and also the 2 factor authentication by adding your cellphone number or you can use Google authenticator https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447?hl=en

To figure out who accessed your account, the Snapchat team should be more than happy to assist or if you want to go further with this, 3rd party services can do the investigation for you as they know the legal procedures need to be followed.

To stay alert, I would recommend signing up to services like https://haveibeenpwned.com may be your email was leaked on a certain site and they got access to your credentials.

Comment: Thank you for the information. The college has been contacted and they are having us forward the emails to them. They informed us that the account was not hacked but accessed by my pw. what kind of legal services could you suggest?

Comment: I also just set up the Snapchat security feature. I don't know why I didn't do this on the account. I have every other account. I feel so mad at myself

Comment: "hey informed us that the account was not hacked but accessed by my pw"   then they don't understand what hacking means. your digital security was breahed. period. and they WILL have the IP address used to log in under your name, they just need to dig.

Comment: it sounds like you probably know the attacker and they have access to your equipment/stored passwords, unless your password is easy to guess, but most colleges don't allow weak passwords...

Answer (score 2):

## Email Geo-location

Depending on which email service provider you are using, you may be able to check the IP address from which the dirty email came.

## Step 1

To do this (with gmail), first, view the email that you would like to track. Find the drop down arrow next to the reply button, and select "Show original". Scroll down and you should be able to see almost everything about the email including the sending and receiving IP addresses.

## Step 2

Go [here](http://aruljohn.com/info/howtofindipaddress/) to see a more detailed tutorial including what to look for in the original message (varies for ESP). After you have the IP address that you suspect to be the attacker's, insert it into [this](https://whatismyipaddress.com/?u=TRUE) free IP Geo-locator.

#### Note - make sure the IP address that you extracted from the email is not yours or your ESP's.